# Copy and paste cells from rows into different columns

Tags: vba, excel

I posted yesterday and received some help that got me started on what I'm trying to do, but unfortunately, I'm stuck again. I have the code calling a inputbox that asks for the day. After entering the date, it searches the sheet for cells containing it, and then copies/pastes them to another sheet.

What I can't seem to figure out how to do, is to get it to paste the way I need it to.

This is my code so far:

```
Private Sub Run_Report_Click()
Dim chdate As Date, datestring As String

datestring = Application.InputBox("Enter Date (MM/DD/YY)", "Date")

If IsDate(datestring) Then
    chdate = DateValue(datestring)
Else
    MsgBox "Invalid Date"
Exit Sub
End If

'input box pop up to allow user to search for
'a specific date

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim xRow, NextRow, LastRow
LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Rows
NextRow = 2
For xRow = 2 To LastRow
    If InStr(Cells(xRow, 1).Value, chdate) > 0 Then
        Rows(xRow).Copy Sheets("TEMP").Rows(NextRow)
        NextRow = NextRow + 1
    End If
    Next xRow
Application.ScreenUpdating = True


MsgBox "Macro is complete, " & NextRow - 2 & " rows containing" & vbCrLf & _
"''" & chdate & "''" & " were copied to TEMP.", 64, "Done"
    End Sub
```

It's pulling data from 15 different columns, and just pasting the specified rows as they are. However, what I am not sure how to do it make it paste some of that information into the same column under a different row. Sort of like this.

1a   2a   3a   4a   5a   6a
1b   2b   3b   4b   5b   6b

to

1a   2a   6a
3a
4a
5a

1b   2b   6b
3b
4b
5b

And then continue on with the rest of the data from the date selected. Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following code instead of your loop (you can keep your inputbox code).

```
Dim wsActive As Worksheet
Dim wsTemp As Worksheet
Dim nRowActive As Long
Dim nCounter As Long
Dim xRow As Long
Dim nRowToUse As Long

Const IADDEND As Integer = 2

Set wsActive = ActiveSheet
Set wsTemp = Sheets("TEMP")

nRowActive = wsActive.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
nCounter = 0

For xRow = 2 To nRowActive
    nRowToUse = nCounter * 4 + IADDEND
    wsTemp.Cells(nRowToUse, 1).Value = wsActive.Cells(xRow, 1).Value
    wsTemp.Cells(nRowToUse, 2).Value = wsActive.Cells(xRow, 2).Value
    wsTemp.Cells(nRowToUse + 1, 1).Value = wsActive.Cells(xRow, 3).Value
    wsTemp.Cells(nRowToUse + 2, 1).Value = wsActive.Cells(xRow, 4).Value
    wsTemp.Cells(nRowToUse + 3, 1).Value = wsActive.Cells(xRow, 5).Value
    wsTemp.Cells(nRowToUse, 3).Value = wsActive.Cells(xRow, 6).Value
    nCounter = nCounter + 1
Next xRow
```

Let me know if this helped.

Comment: That doesn't quite work the way I need it to, but it is definitely the right direction. I think I can understand it from here and get the rest myself. Thank you so much.

Comment: OK! Well, update us here if you need more assistance